# Past perfect or past perfect continuous?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

What is the correct answer to this sentence-
" I ____________(look) for a job for two years before I got this one."
Should it be "I had been looking for a job for two years before I got this one." Or "I had looked for a job for two years before I got this one"?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the past perfect continuous puts more emphasis on the ongoing, perhaps lengthy and laborious, nature of the job-seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I do think I had been looking for a job for two years before I got this one is smoother for me. Because you are talking about something which had been lasting for a period of time. During this time period this thing was happening all the time. So past perfect continuous seems much more appropriate here.